# Не получается подключить Python к С++

Tags: c++, python, компоновщик

Возникла необходимость вызывать в коде C++ скрипты на python.
Сделал тестовый проект в VS 2017. Начал подключать файлы из корневой папки Python.
Как я это делал: открыл свойства проекта (выбрав Все конфигурации). Во вкладке C/C++/Общие добавил дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов (путь до папки include внутри каталога Python).

После этого перешёл в настройки компоновщика и добавил дополнительные каталоги библиотек (путь до папки libs).

В завершение перешёл во вкладку Ввод Компоновщика и добавил дополнительные зависимости (_tkinter.lib
python3.lib
python37.lib)

В итоге при попытке запустить такой код компилятор выдаёт LNK2001 с именами тех функций, которые я вызываю из файла Python.h:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize(); // инициализация интерпретатора
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
        "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    // выполняется нужный скрипт
    Py_Finalize(); // очищение памяти, отданной интерпретатору
    return 0;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как я могу решить эту проблему?

Вот пример выдаваемой ошибки:

```
Ошибка  LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp_Py_Initialize"
```

Comment: Важно добавить: отчаявшись, я пытался просто напросто закинуть .dll файлы в корневую папку проекта, но это ничего не изменило. Складывается ощущение, будто бы функции, на которые ссылается Python.h, лежат не в этих библиотеках вовсе.

Comment: А они лежат в этих библиотеках? посмотрите через dumpbin

Comment: Во "Всех параметрах" написано "<разные параметры>"

Comment: В "Дополнительных параметрах" пусто

Comment: Честно говоря, не уверен, что смогу сделать это быстро (проверить наличие функций), так как до этого ни разу не пользовался этой утилитой. Но везде написано, что все файлы, необходимые для подключения Python находятся в корневой папке (и include и lib)

Comment: В Release x64 и Debug мне удалось найти что-то из командной строки. Но объём текста слишком большой. Приведу лишь некоторые фрагменты: "_tkinter.lib" "python3.lib" "python37.lib" "tcl86t.lib" "tclstub86.lib" "tk86t.lib" "tkstub86.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"                                        "C:\Users\Alexander Furmanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Alexander Furmanov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs"

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, это помогло. Я просто даже и не думал, что 37-32 в названии папки значит разрядность системы. Но сейчас возникла иная проблема: во время запуска выдаёт ошибку (не находит длл). Я их скачал, ошибка стала другой, теперь просто выдаёт её номер: 0x0000007b

Comment: Всё, теперь решилось. Нужно было найти ещё один длл vcruntime140.dll (он лежал в корневой папке). Теперь всё, как надо. Спасибо вам огромное, я бы мог ещё долго не придти к такому решению